# Setting Table Items Across Multiple Threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, user-interface

I'm trying to update the values in a table using a separate worker thread, using POSIX threads.

The function the worker thread is executing is trying to do the following:

```
ui->table->setItem(0,0,new QTableWidgetItem(tr("%1").arg(value)));
```

However, at runtime I get the following error:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QVector<int>'
(Make sure 'QVector<int>' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
```

I'm not quite sure how that `qRegisterMetaType` works. I'm wondering if anyone has any idea how I can grant the worker thread direct access to the widgets?

Comment: There's been some discussion about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872578/how-to-properly-use-qregistermetatype-on-a-class-derived-from-qobject).  In simple terms, it's used to let Qt "know" about other types defined by the user or some external source.  Typically it's required for signals & slots.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Accessing any widget from anything but the main thread is not allowed in Qt. All UI operations need to be done from within the main thread (with a few exceptions, such as painting on a QImage).

In your case, emit a signal in the worker thread when you want to add a new item. In the main thread, have a slot that actually creates the item, i.e. calls `ui->table->setItem(0,0,new QTableWidgetItem(tr("%1").arg(value)));`. Then simply `connect()` the signal and the slot together. Qt will realize that sender and receiver live in different threads and use a `QueuedConnection` automatically. You slot will be called whenever Qt's main thread returns to the event loop.

If your signal has parameters, their type needs to be registered with `qRegisterMetaType`.

Comment: Appreciate the help. After a bit of googling I've come to realize that I'll have to remove multithreading from within the widgets. Could provide an example of how the `qRegisterMetaType` is used to register, let's say, a structure?

Comment: Registering a struct is easy, see the documentation of qRegisterMetaType. Example: qRegisterMetaType<MyStruct>("MyStruct");