# qRegisterMetaType - class, class*, or both

Tags: c++, qt, metaclass

Usually I register my classes in the Qt meta system like this: `qRegisterMetaType<Foo>();`

I have noticed, however, that some people write `qRegisterMetaType<Foo*>();` Is this equivalent? Or do I have to do both, if I want to use pointers with `Foo`?

So is this making any sense?

`qRegisterMetaType<Foo>();`
`qRegisterMetaType<Foo *>();`

Partially answered by [How to properly use qRegisterMetaType on a class derived from QObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872578/how-to-properly-use-qregistermetatype-on-a-class-derived-from-qobject) , but not completely

-- Edit: Interesting answers so far, thanks --

OK, regarding what has been said so far, I made the following conclusion: I want to use my class for both, as pointer and as value, so I register both. Code compiles.

My classes look like this:

```
class Foo1 : public Bar {}
class Foo2 : public Bar {}
```

When I just register the Types all works fine:

```
qRegisterMetaType<Foo1>();
qRegisterMetaType<Foo2>();
```

But when I register:

```
qRegisterMetaType<Foo1*>();
qRegisterMetaType<Foo2*>();
```

code compiles, but at runtime I get:

```
QMetaType:registerTypedef: Binary compatibility break -- Type name Bar* previously registered as typedef of Foo1 [1234], now registering as typedef of Foo2 [1235]
```

So registering as pointer seems to do something different. And I am not able to register both in my particular case.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not equivalent.  `Foo` and `Foo*` are different types and need to be registered separately.  If you only want to store pointer to Foo with the metatype system, then use `qRegisterMetaType<Foo *>();`.  If you want both, then register both.

Normally, you would only register the pointer form if your class cannot be copied, as in the case of `QObject` and derivatives, but this depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from [Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType-2), you should pass type of class, that you want to register. Not a pointer to this type.

I'm not sure, but passing of pointers are usefull if you want to "serialize" pointer value to QVariant.

Comment: That's what I am up to: Is qRegisterMetaType<Foo *>(); nonsens? Making any sense? Should I always do both? I have noticed some people only use qRegisterMetaType<Foo *>(); which is either wrong or clever for some reasons I do not understand.

Comment: I think it nonsens in your context. You should pass only type, not a pointer type. I'm always doing like described in Qt documentation - and all works fine (passing to/from `QVariant`, passing as sigslot arguments and so on).

Comment: It's perfectly fine to use pointer type in the meta type system. But it's not convenient to pass pointers through it because of ownership and deletion time issues.