# How Could I Register Types With A Deleted Copy Constructor To QMetaType?

Tags: c++, qt, qmetatype

#### The Problem:

I want to create an object instance at runtime using QMetaType by the type name. But I couldn't register the type because it's a `QObject` and I don't have access to the implementation to change it.

#### Duplicate Question(s):

- [How to properly use qRegisterMetaType on a class derived from QObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872578/how-to-properly-use-qregistermetatype-on-a-class-derived-from-qobject)

  - I couldn't understand from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7877659/9248466) to where I have to define the specialization of `qMetaTypeConstructHelper`.

#### Reproducible Example Of The Problem:

<sub>The CMake: [CMakeLists.txt](https://gist.github.com/gccore/897766cf91529cdb4eea1e67c833adcc)</sub>

```cpp
#include <QMetaType>
#include <QObject>

class MyObject : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
};

#include "main.moc"

int main()
{
  qRegisterMetaType<MyObject>("MyObject");
  int const type_id = QMetaType::type("MyObject");
}
```

It will fail:

```cpp
/tmp/untitled1/main.cc:12:3: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'qRegisterMetaType<MyObject>' requested here
  qRegisterMetaType<MyObject>("MyObject");
  ^
/tmp/untitled1/main.cc:4:18: note: copy constructor of 'MyObject' is implicitly deleted because base class 'QObject' has a deleted copy constructor
class MyObject : public QObject {
                 ^
/opt/Qt/5.15.2/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qobject.h:467:20: note: 'QObject' has been explicitly marked deleted here
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(QObject)
                   ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A Non-portable And Non-documented Solution:

Specialize the `QtMetaTypePrivate::QMetaTypeFunctionHelper` for your type:

```cpp
namespace QtMetaTypePrivate
{
template <>
struct QMetaTypeFunctionHelper<MyObject, true> {
  static void Destruct(void *address)
  {
    static_cast<MyObject *>(address)->~MyObject();
  }

  static void *Construct(void *where, void const *address)
  {
    if (address != nullptr) {
      delete static_cast<MyObject const *>(address);
    }
    return where != nullptr ? new (where) MyObject : new MyObject;
  }
};
}  // namespace QtMetaTypePrivate
```

### Using `QMetaObject`, But Requires A `Q_INVOKABLE` Constructor:

By not providing a Public Copy Constructor one solution is to register a pointer type:

```cpp
qRegisterMetaType<MyObject*>();
```

And then retrieve the type ID using `"MyObject*"` string and the `QMetaObject` using `QMetaType::metaObjectForType`:

```cpp
int const type_id = QMetaType::type("MyObject*");
QMetaObject const* metaObject = QMetaType::metaObjectForType(type_id);
```

And now we could create an instance of the class:

```cpp
QObject* instance = metaObject->newInstance();
```

But still, we need to have an invokable public constructor:

```cpp
class MyObject : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Q_INVOKABLE MyObject()
  {}
};
```

https://interest.qt-project.narkive.com/zP6wxOZf/how-to-create-qobject-derived-class-instance-from-class-name#post7